# What pitch attitudes are common during an emergency descent for an airliner?

Tags: boeing-737, airbus-a320, emergency-procedures, pitch

What pitch attitudes are common during an emergency descent? I assume it would be a fairly nose-down attitude, but I can't imagine how steep would feel to the passengers.

Suppose a gradual decompression takes place and no structural damage is present nor suspected. What would be the pitch attitude for common airliners like the Airbus A320 or the Boeing 737?

Comment: fun video on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHawjB2PzK0

Comment: @Cloud Nice video! If you look carefully at around 2:40 they start descending. You can just about see the vertical speed on the PFD going down. Note how smooth it is :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not as nose down as you may think. First, let us have a look at *normal* pitch attitudes during a *normal* descent (without speedbrake). These can be found in the QRH Performance Inflight Tables:

[image: Normal Descent Table]
<sup>(Boeing 737 NG QRH - 30.1 Performance Inflight - Flight With Unreliable Airspeed)</sup>

As you can see, normal descent attitudes are varying between -2.5° and 2.0° depending on aircraft weight and altitude.

For an *emergency descent* you would extend the speedbrakes which allows a steeper descent. The FCTM has some details on the procedure (see also [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/69998/would-a-737-pilot-use-flaps-in-nose-dive/69999#69999) for more details):

> To manually fly the maneuver, disconnect the autothrottles and retard thrust levers
> to idle. Smoothly extend the speedbrakes, disengage the autopilot and smoothly
> lower the nose to initial descent attitude (**approximately 10° nose down**).
>
> About 10 knots before reaching target speed, slowly **raise the pitch attitude** to
> maintain target speed. Keep the airplane in trim at all times. If MMO/VMO is
> inadvertently exceeded, change pitch smoothly to decrease speed.

<sup>(Boeing 737 NG FCTM - 7.7 Maneuvers - Rapid Descent, emphasis mine)</sup>

Note that the **10° nose down attitude** is only the *initial* pitch to start the descent and increase airspeed to MMO/VMO. Afterwards, the nose is raised to maintain the speed limit. This means the pitch will be between -10° and -2.5° during most of the emergency descent. Enough to notice it, but hardly the nose dive some Hollywood movies show.

Comment: I disagree. I think you'd experience zero G in an emergency descent

Comment: @Cloud For sure not. Note words like "smoothly lower the nose" are chosen in the Boeing documents. Basically, you should not rapidly start the descent. The Zero G flights (the intentional ones) get zero G by flying on a parabola to achieve this (meaning you get zero G long before they actually descend).

Comment: By all means, @Cloud, please write up an answer of your own referencing documentation of a procedure for a major commercial airliner that would produce a zero-G emergency descent.

Comment: @Cloud you may experience a low load factor when putting the aircraft in a dive but then you rapidly reach max speed and continue on a straight path at constant speed (no acceleration and thus you experience 1G), but zero-G seems to be an extremely low load factor.

Comment: If I read this table correctly, an emergency descent from 40,000 feet at a weight of 80,000Kg requires a pitch attitude of 0.0° and generates a -3400 ft/min vertical speed? What the heck pitch attitude does one fly at at that altitude and weight to maintain a constant altitude??

Comment: @FreeMan Careful, the table is for **normal** descent (no speedbrake). To answer your question: maintaining 40,000ft at that weight is not even possible. The cruise table in the QRH lists a pitch of 3.5° for **60t** weight for 40,000ft and also a pitch of 3.5° for 80t weight at **35,000ft** (which is about the max. altitude for this weight).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I presumed, since you presented it in reference to a question on emergency descent and the graph labeling says "Flight With Unreliable Airspeed", that this was for emergency descent. Still though, 3400ft/min descent rate is pretty decent...

Comment: @FreeMan: it's not as much about pitch as it is about having engines. If you are doing en emergency descent, first (or second) thing you would do is retard the engines. Also, at 40000ft, with 180kt IAS (so about 360TAS, say), that rate of descent corresponds to an L/D of about 11:1, which sounds about right for a jetliner at idle.

Comment: @Cloud Remember that what you can feel is _acceleration_, not vertical speed itself. Even if you're descending at 10,000 feet per minute, if it's a constant 10,000 fpm, you will feel 1 G just like you would in level flight. There's absolutely no need to accelerate downward at 1 G (what is required to feel 0 G) to enter an emergency descent. That would be an acceleration of 1,920 feet per minute _per second_. So, 5 seconds of that and you'd have a vertical speed of nearly -10,000 fpm. Extreme maneuvers to shave a few seconds off of a minutes-long descent aren't necessary.

Comment: *"the nose dive some Hollywood movies show"* is often made even worse by many movies adding the Stuka siren sound effects (which in real life was a device deliberately added to make that sound, in order to frighten the enemy), so many people associate any aircraft which is rapidly descending with that loud wailing.

Answer (score 14):

My experience was on the Regional Jets but from sim training I recall that the pitch down once at Vmo with flight spoilers extended was somewhere around 10-15 deg.  The standard procedure for the CRJ was to declare "emergency descent", slam the thrust levers to idle, flight spoilers fully out, dial the Autopilot altitude preselect to 10000 ft, select the Autopilot to Speed Mode, and dial the speed select to Vmo, and just let the airplane do its thing while the two of you went through the QRH.

You will get a small G reduction during the pushover, but the AP would pushover gently enough to avoid making people in the back float around.  If you push over manually, there is a risk of pushing too hard in the stress of the situation and banging heads against the ceiling in the back (it doesn't take much when you're going fast like that).

Any G reduction that occurs is only momentarily during the pushover.  Once up to speed you are back to 1 G more or less. The pitch attitude in the descent would be noticeable to a passenger looking out the window from the slanting horizon, but I don't think it would look like they were diving straight at the ground.  The scarier part would be the rumble from the spoilers being out, and the roar in the cabin from flying at Vmo.